# Append data frame to another data frame with different column names

Tags: r

I'm trying to add one data frame as rows to another data frame.  The column names don't match, so I have a lookup table that matches them.  I thought I would be able to do each column one at a time in a loop, but I keep getting `replacement has 209 rows, data has 157` error.

How can I add them all at once?  Here's an example of what I'm trying to do:

I've got two data sets

```
test1 = c("one", "two", "three", "four", "five")
test2 = c("1", "3", "4", "5")
```

And a lookup table to match the column names

```
first second
1   one      1
2 three      3
3  four      4
4  five      5
```

So I'd like to append all the rows from "1" into "one", "3" into "three" etc.  I've tried a few different things and gotten errors either about the number of rows or the fact that I don't have replacements for each value, like in my example I'm ignoring the column "two".

Could anyone recommend how to do this?

Comment: Can you show your expected output? And why are you calling vectors datasets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there any reason you're opposed to setting the names of the two sets to be the same?

`rbind` will work just fine in that case, and you can just use something like `names(test2) <- lookup_table$first` so that the names match up.

Comment: That's a good idea, I'm not opposed to that.  How would I do it though?  Using `for(i in nrows(lookup) { colnames(test1)[lookup[i,1]] }` doesn't work because `colnames(test1)[lookup[1,1]]` returns `NA`

Comment: I should clarify that the reason I don't use what you suggested is that the order of the columns doesn't match up in my database, I need to look up what name gets mapped to what

Comment: `rbind.fill()` partially solved this for me, but I'm still not able to figure out how to change the variable names from the lookup table