# Rename columns from a lookup table

Tags: r

I'm trying to rename the columns in a data frame using matching from a lookup table.

```
oldvars = c("mpg", "cyl" , "disp",  "hp", "drat", "wt", "qsec", "vs", "am", "gear", "carb")
newvars = c("Miles Per Gallon", "Cycle", "Displacement", "Horsepower", "Distance Rating", 
"Working Time", "Quick Second", "Versus", "America", "Gears", "Carbohydrates")

lookup = data.frame(oldvars, newvars)
mycars = mtcars
```

Using the lookup list to match oldvars and change them into newvars, so that `names(mycars)` would output `"Miles Per Gallon", "Cycle", "Displacement", "Horsepower", "Distance Rating", "Working Time", "Quick Second", "Versus", "America", "Gears", "Carbohydrates"`

I've tried using `colnames` to change the names but it isn't reading the variable like I was expecting.  The following

```
for(i in 1:length(newvars)) {
  colnames(mycars)[oldvars[i]] = newvars[i]
}
```

just outputs `NA`s

Comment: Subset `names(test)` by "second" and assign the value of `lookup$first`.

Comment: Please provide a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/1412059).

Comment: Instead of a new question to get more responses, this should be added to your original question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34723607/append-data-frame-to-another-data-frame-with-different-column-names

Comment: @Roland I completely re-wrote my question, wrote it after spending too long staring at it this morning.  It is now reproducible and shows expected output

Comment: @PierreLafortune it's related but it's a separate question.  I felt it was worth a separate post, I'm not just being a pain and abusing the system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it with a double for loop

```
for(i in 1:length(newvars)) {
  for(z in 1:length(newvars)) {
    if(colnames(mycars)[i] == oldvars[z]) {
      colnames(mycars)[i] = newvars[z]
    }
  }
}
```

Highly inefficient but it gets the job done

Comment: The *double*  loop certainly isn't needed. `nn = names(mycars); for(i in 1:length(oldvars)){name(mycars)[nn == oldvars[i]] = newvars[i]}` will do.

Answer (score 10):

If you know they're in the same order (as they are in your example) then the answer is easy:

```
names(mycars) = newvars
```

---

However, let's focus on a more general case - not all column need renaming, and there might be some extra  names in the name vector, and the order is not necessarily the same:

```
old_vars = c("cyl" ,"mpg",  "disp",  "foo")
new_vars = c( "Cycle", "Miles Per Gallon", "Displacement", "bar")
lookup = data.frame(old_vars, new_vars)

mycars = head(mtcars, 2) # short data frame to work with
```

Then `match` is your friend for determining the correct order:

```
name_match = match(names(mycars), lookup$old_vars)
name_match
[1]  2  1  3 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA

# assign the names
names(mycars)[na.omit(name_match)] = lookup$new_vars[!is.na(name_match)]
```

---

`data.table` has a really nice interface for this, `setnames` accepts a vector of old and new names

```
library(data.table)
setDT(mycars) # convert the data frame to data.table
setnames(mycars, old = lookup$old_vars, new = lookup$new_vars) # update names by reference
```

The old `plyr` package has a `rename` function that accepts a named vector, where the vector values are the new names  and the vector names are the old names:

```
plyr::rename(mycars, setNames(lookup$new_vars, lookup$old_vars))
```

Comment: I love this solution except that in my case I only want to rename some of the columns, and this turns the ones I am not renaming into NAs.

Comment: @Gregor, is there a dplyr/piping alternative to parallel the `setNames` solution?

Comment: @chrowe edited to take care of NAs. Emman, not that I know of.

Comment: @GregorThomas I was trying the "more general" base R solution above and it's yielding a lot of `NA`s, seems something is wrong. Also @fantanaman's corrected version of this (below) is not working. My own base R solution (not posted) is pretty verbose, I thought there might be something simpler.

Comment: Hey @TimTeaFan that's interesting to hear. Care to share an example?

Comment: @GregorThomas: Sorry, I didn't mention I was talking about the `mycars` example above. I now figured why the code yielded `NA`s. In your answer you use `lookup$oldvars` in `match()`, and I had the `lookup` df loaded from the OPs post. Maybe you can replace `lookup$oldvars` with just `oldvars` which you define in your answer (unlike `lookup` which comes from the OP). I think this is the reason @fantaman below supplied a corrected version.

Comment: @TimTeaFan I added a `lookup` definition in my answer and switched my column names to include underscores so there shouldn't be any more confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Adding as answer only because I can't comment yet.

In @Gregor Thomas's correct answer, I suggest to reverse the arguments in the `match()` call, to account for cases where matching `oldvars` are not continuous from the first element in `names(mycars)`. Full example below since I have the space.

```
mycars = head(mtcars, 2)    

oldvars = c("cyl" ,"mpg",  "wt",  "foo") #note change to variable selection in lookup
newvars = c( "Cycle", "Miles Per Gallon", "Weight", "bar")
name_match = match(names(mycars), oldvars)
name_match
[1]  2  1 NA NA NA  3 NA NA NA NA NA

#After omitting the `NA` elements, the match vector no longer properly aligns with
#the names(mycars) vector

names(mycars)[na.omit(name_match)] = newvars[!is.na(name_match)]
names(mycars) 
[1] "Miles Per Gallon" "Cycle"            NA   
[4] "hp"               "drat"             "wt"
[7] "qsec"             "vs"               "am"
[10] "gear"             "carb"

#instead, reverse the arguments in match() to find the data.frame names that appear in the lookup

name_match = match(oldvars, names(mycars))
name_match
[1]  2  1  6 NA
names(mycars)[na.omit(name_match)] = newvars[!is.na(name_match)]
names(mycars)
[1] "Miles Per Gallon" "Cycle"            "disp" 
[4] "hp"               "drat"             "Weight" 
[7] "qsec"             "vs"               "am"    
[10] "gear"             "carb"
```

Comment: It's ok to post another answer fixing something in the existing answer, so it is not needed to explain yourself at the start. But remember each answer should be comprehensive on its own.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one approach using a named vector with `dplyr::any_of()` inside `dplyr::rename()`. `any_of()` is helpful if not all of the columns in the named vector are present in the data.

```r
library(dplyr)

recode_vec <- setNames(lookup$oldvars, lookup$newvars)

mycars %>% 
  rename(any_of(recode_vec)) %>% 
  glimpse() # for better printing

#> Rows: 32
#> Columns: 11
#> $ `Miles Per Gallon` <dbl> 21.0, 21.0, 22.8, 21.4, 18.7, 18.1, 14.3, 24.4, 22.…
#> $ Cycle              <dbl> 6, 6, 4, 6, 8, 6, 8, 4, 4, 6, 6, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, …
#> $ Displacement       <dbl> 160.0, 160.0, 108.0, 258.0, 360.0, 225.0, 360.0, 14…
#> $ Horsepower         <dbl> 110, 110, 93, 110, 175, 105, 245, 62, 95, 123, 123,…
#> $ `Distance Rating`  <dbl> 3.90, 3.90, 3.85, 3.08, 3.15, 2.76, 3.21, 3.69, 3.9…
#> $ `Working Time`     <dbl> 2.620, 2.875, 2.320, 3.215, 3.440, 3.460, 3.570, 3.…
#> $ `Quick Second`     <dbl> 16.46, 17.02, 18.61, 19.44, 17.02, 20.22, 15.84, 20…
#> $ Versus             <dbl> 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, …
#> $ America            <dbl> 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, …
#> $ Gears              <dbl> 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, …
#> $ Carbohydrates      <dbl> 4, 4, 1, 1, 2, 1, 4, 2, 2, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, …
```

Data from OP

```r
oldvars = c("mpg", "cyl" , "disp",  "hp", "drat", "wt", "qsec", "vs", "am", "gear", "carb")
newvars = c("Miles Per Gallon", "Cycle", "Displacement", "Horsepower", "Distance Rating", 
"Working Time", "Quick Second", "Versus", "America", "Gears", "Carbohydrates")

lookup = data.frame(oldvars, newvars)
mycars = mtcars
```

<sup>Created on 2023-01-15 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

In base R we can do :

```r
old_vars = c("cyl" ,"mpg",  "disp")
new_vars = c( "Cycle", "Miles Per Gallon", "Displacement")
names(mtcars) <- replace(setNames(nm = names(mtcars)), old_vars, new_vars)
head(mtcars,1)
#>           Miles Per Gallon Cycle Displacement  hp drat   wt  qsec vs am gear
#> Mazda RX4               21     6          160 110  3.9 2.62 16.46  0  1    4
#>           carb
#> Mazda RX4    4
```

<sup>Created on 2023-05-28 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Or with pipes :

```
mtcars %>%
  setNames(replace(setNames(nm = names(.)), old_vars, new_vars))

mtcars |>
  (\(x) setNames(x, replace(setNames(nm = names(x)), old_vars, new_vars)))()
```